# How to dynamically add attributes in vue.js components

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, web

I am making a news website using NYT REST API. I want to add attributes to the components dynamically using the *document.getElementsByClassName()*

For Example, I want to add a title to my component (the title is a prop actually of type String), I want to add it dynamically using a loop. I have added it normally in the given code snippet, but what if I have 30 components and I have data in an array and I want to give title from that array.

```
<News_Card class="card" :title='this.all_data[0].title' />
```

I want this *:title='this.all_data[0].title* to be added using loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `v-for` directive to render the `all_data` items :

```
<News_Card class="card" v-for="(item,index) in all_data" 
                    :title='item.title' :key="index" />
```